# Не закрываются автоматически скобки и кавычки

Tags: jade, webstorm, pug

Начал работать с `pug`в `Webstorm` и обнаружил, что скобки и кавычки автоматически не закрываются. Жутко неудобно. Например, когда я набираю в обычном `html` `"` или `(` или `{`, то все они автоматически закрываются. В `.pug` файлах такого почему-то не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему? Это баг или фича такая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это - отсутствующие фичи:) Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за [WEB-27902](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27902) и [WEB-18390](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18390)

Comment: а как там проголосовать? :)

Comment: см. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications